# Can the point draw using drawContours be use?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Using the functions findContours and approxPolyDP to find  the contours of the elements of an image. Using this points I used the drawContours function to draw the polygon in a new image.
 I want to use all the points generated by drawContours function in order to obtain the centroid and major axes of the figures, is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to draw the contours to another image. Just loop through them, calculate the moments of them and then the center of mass (centroid), main axis angle for each moment.

**Code (not tested):**

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

[...]

// Get contours
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

// Get the moments
vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
  mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false ); 
}

// Get the mass centers
vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
  mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 ); 
}

// Get the angle of the main axis
vector<double> ama( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
  ama[i] = 0.5*atan2((2*mu[i].mu11),(mu[i].mu20-mu[i].mu02)); //need to be 2 arguments
}
```

Hope that helps! For further information take a look at these links:

- [Image Moments | AI Shack](http://aishack.in/tutorials/image-moments/)
- [Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors > moments](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html#moments)
- [Image Moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know that the centroid and major axe, can be calculate in this way, but I have already calculated the centroid and  major axe in a different way, using just the contour points to find it. I wanted to use the point in the poligon draw by the function drawContours, in order to see if the centroid and major axe calculated from the contour points are the same. This is the reason that I want to use the points drawn by the drawCountour function in order to calculate the major axe.

Comment: You should mention this in your question :P